# ext4-fs and IO errors with Samsung 960 pro 512 GB on linux mint 18.3

Tags: linux-mint, ssd, nvme

So my pc began failing last week giving me ext4-fs and IO errors, after like 1 year using the ssd without hiccups. 
I have a Samsung 960 pro 512GB. I searched around and found that some people got these errors, tried the workarounds and it won't work. If i boot windows 10 and use Crystalmark, it says the ssd is perfectly fine. I don't use windows very much but didn't observe any crashes while using it. Samsung Magician says everything is fine and latest firmware is installed. I'm using linux mint 18.3. 
Also, after a few reboots, the system works perfectly like nothing happened, but if I reboot again, the errors come back.
SMART log:
'''
sudo nvme smart-log /dev/nvme0n1
Smart Log for NVME device:nvme0n1 namespace-id:ffffffff
critical_warning                    : 0
temperature                         : 31 C
available_spare                     : 100%
available_spare_threshold           : 10%
percentage_used                     : 0%
data_units_read                     : 6.777.003
data_units_written                  : 5.161.368
host_read_commands                  : 161.531.212
host_write_commands                 : 111.780.796
controller_busy_time                : 638
power_cycles                        : 1.678
power_on_hours                      : 550
unsafe_shutdowns                    : 596
media_errors                        : 0
num_err_log_entries                 : 246
Warning Temperature Time            : 0
Critical Composite Temperature Time : 0
Temperature Sensor 1                : 31 C
Temperature Sensor 2                : 33 C
Thermal Management T1 Trans Count   : 0
Thermal Management T2 Trans Count   : 0
Thermal Management T1 Total Time    : 0
Thermal Management T2 Total Time    : 0
'''

Comment: Try running `smartctl -a /dev/your device` and check what's after `=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===` (or post it here). There is chance that programs you have mentioned are already checking SMART data, but it's good to be sure.

Comment: so, after 3 days, it is now working perfectly as if nothing happened... just can't understand why

Comment: the smartctl -a command returns an error that says it can't detect device type and I don't know how to make it work

Comment: smartctl --all /dev/nvme0n1p5
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-58-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

/dev/nvme0n1p5: Unable to detect device type
Please specify device type with the -d option.

Use smartctl -h to get a usage summary

Comment: managed to get the smart report